Can Google AppScript automatically match the email templates to the attachments or files saved on a certain folder?
The scenario is:
We receive files or different letters from an office. The email template or cover letter varies depending on the files or attachments.
Most of the time it is hard to identify what email template should be used for a certain file. We use templates feature on Gmail but we cannot search nor correctly identify what template is needed to be used for the certain file.
We would like to know if we can automate:

Automatically detect/ identify the files or new files saved on the drive and match it to the right template.

Thank you!
I am looking into using Google App Script.
I tried using templates on Gmail but it is hard since there is no search bar or if I identified the file correctly and if I match it to the right template.

If you are having trouble determining what template should be linked to what email automating it won't be possible. You need to be able to search the contents of the email looking for specific characteristics within each to email in order to determine which templated to use.  So solve the problem in your mind before trying to automate.
